# VBA code (if needed) to save new Word document in same directory as other Word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word

Many users, myself included, begin editing a Word document, create a new Word doc, and wish to save the second doc in the same directory as the first doc. This is the default behavior in an editor such as emacs. Word 2013, alas, makes me pick the directory ("Folder") where I wish to save the new file, forcing me to select among various network folders and then select multiple subdirectories before I reach the one containing my first document. I used to have a simple VBA script that would find the directory of the first file and then save the new file in that directory, or at least it would set the directory of the first file as the default directory for saving files. Does anyone have code to do what I'm looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will the working directory to the directory of the first file you were working on:

```
ChDir(Application.Documents(Application.Documents.Count).Path)
```

If you want to save the most recent opened document to the same location as the first file you were working on, then try the following

```
Sub SaveWithFirstFile()
NewFileName = "filename1.docx
Application.Documents(1).SaveAs2 FileName:=Application.Documents(Application.Documents.Count).Path & "\\" & NewFileName
End Sub
```

Change "filename1.docx" to what you want it to

Comment: Thanks. I ran this code: `Sub UpdateWD()
    ChDir (Application.Documents(Application.Documents.Count).Path)
End Sub` But when I went to save the new document, I was presented with the same list of shared drives, folders, etc. So the code didn't seem to do anything. Do I need more steps in the macro?

Comment: If you want to save the most recent opened document to the same folder as the document you opened first, see my updated answer for a solution. Does that help?